# FTDI board shows only one location id on dual channel 2232H

Tags: ftdi

This is a software question, but I believe people working with this board might have come across this scenario before. I have a FT2232H board that has two channels. I want to program it with an xml file to get the right configuration.

When I connect it to FT Prog, I see only one location Id. I am still able to program the device, but I don't think it gets configured correctly as the ports do not get enumerated correctly (I don't see a COM port and one JTAG, just one JTAG).

When connected on a different computer, it shows up as two location IDs and the xml file programming configured my device correctly, resulting in a JTAG port and a serial COM port.

I am not entirely sure what is happening here, could be related to drivers or something else. Has anyone seen this happen?

Comment: Could be an OS issue. Is one Windows and another Linux? FTDI chips come pre-loaded with drivers for both, but could be Linux it tries first. Also, does it have a config EEPROM?

Comment: Actually both were Windows machines :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, but I would set up both Windows PC's to do a long boot instead of a fast one. When booting up press the F2 key to open the bios editor, and under POST you should see and fast or slow boot option. Choose 'slow' and save and exit.

A slow boot forces bios to search for any and all new devices added or removed, then it can build a correct .dmi file (device master index) for the OS to use when it loads in.

I could not get my Windows 7 64 bit workstation (Dell 690) to 'see' that I now had 2 video cards and 4 monitors until I did several long boots in a row. Then I went back to a fast boot and all was ok. So a long boot has you waiting a minute or more but will catch any hardware changes made. If it works do several in a row so Windows puts the change in its own logs.